# Is there some elementary proof for Bertrand's Postulate for n is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the sequence of primes.

$p_n<2p_{n-1}$

Is there some elementary proof?

Comment: Essentially, there is Chebyshev's estimate for the density of primes, and there is no going around it.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin it's guaranteed if we assume Goldbach. Grimms predicts it as well. Legendre predicts it as well above n=2. Admittedly, unproven.

Comment: Yeah, that will do... sort of.

Comment: doh got the n wrong n=5

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I hope you do not suggest to prove Bertrand's postulate with Goldbach's conjecture. The comment sounds so.

Comment: I more meant we can't assume any of those conjectures and have it be false. I problem of course is There's no known elementary proof of any of them.